# Client error 404: how to catch and gracefully handle it?

Tags: php, symfony, exception, guzzle

I am using Symfony 5.2.1 to consume an API.

The API returns HTTP response with 404 status if an object is not found (in my case it is a book). Sample output as below:

```
{
    "statusCode": 404,
    "data": "Book 01986 not found"
}
```

[image]

When I call this API in my Symfony Controller (using Guzzle to make client calls):

```
public function detail($bookid): Response {
        $uri = "book/$bookid";
        try {
            $res = $this->service->getService()->get($uri);
        } catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception $e) {
            echo"error";
            die();
        }
        dump($res);
        die();
        $book = json_decode((string) ($this->service->getService()->get($uri)->getBody()))->data;
        dump($book);
        die();

        return $this->render('book/detail.html.twig', ['book' => $book]);
    }
```

It prompts in my browser something like this:

[image]

I want to catch this error and then do some graceful handling in my frontend web app.

**Note: currently the environment is set to DEV, not PROD.**

Answer (score 6):

you need to catch Client exception, you can even catch all request exception & pinpoint the 404 exceptions with status code.

```
 try {
          $res = $this->service->getService()->get($uri);
     } catch (\GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
          if($e->hasResponse()){
              if ($e->getResponse()->getStatusCode() == '404'){ // to pinpoint 404 errors
                  // get your 404 error message using this $e->getMessage();
              }
          }
     }
```